# will this allow an EC2 instance to access another EC2 instances without credential?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I know if I create a role and assign AmazonS3FullAccess permission to it, any EC2 instances assume this role will be able to use S3 with full privilege.

on the same token, if I create a role

1. Choose the service that will use this role: **EC2**
2. Attach permissions policies: **AmazonEC2FullAccess**, 
   Policy ARN arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess

then I assign this role to an EC2 instance A, my question is,

will instance A have access to all other EC2 instances?
If I want to ssh from instance A to instance X, I would still need ssh keys as if there were not roles assigned it, right? what is the point of roles in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning this role only means that you will have access to all EC2 APIs without any credentials. If you are trying to connect to other instance using SSH, this won't satisfy that. However, you can perform any EC2 API call on any of the EC2 instance.

Comment: thanks for your response, so on Instance A, anyone who knows programming can issue any commands here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html, to instance X? what are the guardrails to help unwanted behaviors through API calls?